# VS 2010 adding spaces at line end in AssemblyInfo.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working in VB in Visual Studio 2010, trying to keep the lines in my AssemblyInfo.vb file clear of extra whitespace at the end. I track my projects with git using GitHub's Windows client and the powershell environment it ships with, so when I do a git diff I get red marks wherever there's erroneous whitespace.

Basically what I've found is that if I remove the whitespace in Visual Studio and save the file, it comes back. If I remove it in Notepad++, save, and reopen it in Visual Studio, the whitespace stays gone. After that, as soon as I change anything on a line, Visual Studio adds a space to the end of each line that I've changed which happens to end with > otherwise. If I change the end of the tag to />, it doesn't add the space, but of course that doesn't compile.

I've dug through the Text Editor settings for Basic, XML, and All Languages, but don't see any setting specific to this. Is there one I'm missing, or should I plan on using notepad for version changes? I'll also mention that I have Visual Studio 2012 on my personal machine, and it doesn't seem to do this there.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you cannot use project properties?

[image]

Comment: I prefer text editors and keyboard shortcuts over excessive clicking. If I have the AssemblyInfo file open anyway, I can hit Ctrl+Tab, Ctrl+End, left a couple times, and make my change. And for the record, with the "Pretty listing" setting turned on, using the dialog you suggested gets me the same whitespace on the end of whatever lines have changed.

Comment: @Amazingant: just wondering how many (thousand) times a day you prepare new deployments, to make this keyboard shortcut feasible. :)

Comment: @Neolist not nearly often enough to be worth the difference, but I like keyboard shortcuts :P

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it. For future reference, it's part of "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code" in Text Editor > Basic > VB Specific. Thought I had that turned off already.